# Cognos calculate using a different layout section

Tags: cognos-bi

I have a Cognos report that has four different sections/layouts, each containing their own list. I would like to use one section to perform calculations using another list from another section. Is that possible?

For example:

Section Two contains a list with Name, Week1 Commissions, Week2 Commissions, etc
I want Section One to calculate the first 11 weeks only so the List in Section One would contain
Name, Weeks 1 through 11 total.

What is the best way to make this happen if it's possible.

Section One would contain these columns which would perform the calculations

Name  Week 1-11 totals          |

Section Two would have these columns

Name  Week 1    Week 2    Week 3   .....

Best,

Kev

Comment: What have you tried?
List 1 has commissions, what does list 2 have for a metric?
How does list 1 influence the other lists -- list 2,3, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and you can perform all of the logic in one query

There are many ways to do this

For example,  the four different sections/layouts, selecting the list, go to properties you can use the same query for each list